# How to have config option in Makefile

Tags: makefile, config

My main project directory has 4 sub-directories and each sub directory has some .c and .S files. I have written only one Makefile outside which contains lines like this:

```
...

AS_SRC= $(wildcard cpu/*.S) $(wildcard drivers/*.S) $(wildcard lib/*.S) $(wildcard init/*.S)
C_SRC= $(wildcard cpu/*.c) $(wildcard drivers/*.c) $(wildcard lib/*.c) $(wildcard init/*.c)

OBJS =  $(AS_SRC:.S=.o) $(C_SRC:.c=.o)

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET).bin

%.o: %.S
    @$(CC) -x assembler-with-cpp $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.c
    @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@

$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJS)
    @$(CC) $^ $(LFLAGS) -o $@

$(TARGET).bin: $(TARGET).elf
    @$(OC) -S -O binary $< $@

...
```

I understand that this is not a very good way to write Makefile. I want to have a .config file based on which It will be decided on what files to compile. Also I would like to use those config options in code something like `#ifdef CONFIG_SOMETHING`. I tried to understand from main Makefile of Linux kernel code and implement something similar, however that Makefile seems too complex.

Can anyone give suggestion on how to go about it? I already tried searching google but couldn't find any hint on how to go about having a config file.

Comment: it sounds like you're looking for GNU autotools, which would generate a config.h file you could include and then use the config variables in your code

Comment: @jenesaisquoi and if I want to compile only specific files, does it also provide option for that?

Comment: the build system will generate makefiles, so you should be able to do everything you can do in a regular makefile.  I'm no expert on autotools -- it is very configurable and quite complex

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Ok thanks I'll have a look.

Comment: I don't see anything much wrong with this makefile (although I personally prefer to list out files in my makefiles rather than use `wildcard`).  We can't really give much advice unless you describe what you mean by _decide on what files to compile_; do you sometimes not want to compile them all?  Why?  In what situations?  Also in what situations do you want to use different preprocessor macros?

Comment: I also think the question is unclear, but at the very least you can simplify the `wildcard` statements: `AS_SRC= $(wildcard cpu/*.S drivers/*.S lib/*.S init/*.S)`

Answer (score 1):

If the config file follows the Makefile rules (var=value), you can use include

In your Makefile:

```
CONFIG = default.config
include ${CONFIG}

ifdef (... test on CONFIG setting)
endif
```

When make is invoked without parameters (that is `make target`), it will use the 'default' config file (default.config above). To run make with a different config use `make CONFIG=alt.config ...`